# Continuity of log(x) as a multiplication operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis

Define a multiplication operator $T_{log}f(x) = f(x)\cdot log(x)$. For $1 \le p < \infty$ and the usual Lebesgue space $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, is $T_{log}$ a continuous operator from $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ to itself? I know this is not true for $p = \infty$ and I feel this should be true for finite $p$. But I don't know how to prove it or if there exist counter examples.

Comment: In general, if $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, then the only way to get $\|fg\|_{L^{p}(X)} \leq C \|f\|_{L^{p}(X)}$ for all $f \in L^{p}(X)$ is if $\|g\|_{L^{q}(X)} \leq C$.  (These are, in fact, equivalent statements.)

Comment: @PeterMorfe That's not correct. The multiplication operator is bounded from $L^p$ to $L^1$ if and only if $g\in L^q$, but it is bounded from $L^p$ to $L^p$ if and only if $g\in L^\infty$.

Comment: You're right, I messed up the exponents.  But same issue...

Comment: The correct statement is, for $p,q,r \in [1,\infty)$ with $\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}$, the function $g$ has $\|fg\|_{L^{r}(X)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^{p}(X)}$ for all $f \in L^{p}(X)$ if and only if $g \in L^{q}(X)$ and $\|g\|_{L^{q}(X)} \leq C$.  (Exercise using Holder's inequality and $L^{p}-L^{q}$ duality.)   Above $r = p$ so $q = \infty$.  At any rate, the logarithm isn't in any $L^{p}$ space on $\mathbb{R}$.